# Cart empty issue in magento2

Tags: php-7, magento-2.2.5

I have get the new quote for every page reload in when the cart is empty.

If anyone face this issue....How to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure: Are you getting a new quote every time you reload the page when the cart is empty or do you have to get a new quote, everytime you reload the page and the cart is empty?

Comment: I'm getting a new quote every time , reload the page when the cart is empty...I want to fix the creating new quote

Comment: If you didn't override any core-functions that interfere with the quote generation you should check the lifetime of your quote.

You can check that in your Backend>Shops>Configuration>Sales>Checkout>Cart>"Quote-Lifetime"

Check out
Backend>Shops>Configuration>Web> Default Cookie Settings>Cookie-Lifetime

Comment: Addtition: You should check, if you are deleting your session anywhere. Deleting the session naturally ends in a new generation of a cart for guests. You can make a cart/quote persistent in the backend, which should fix that issue for your logged in costumers.

Backend>Shops>Configurations>Costumers>Current/existing Cart(not sure how it's named in english)>Activate Persistency set to yes

Comment: But i have get the new quote for every hit (Ex:QuoteNo :554,555,556,557.....)

Comment: In guest cart.........

Comment: Are you resetting your session every reload anywhere in your code or creating a new one?

Comment: Have you checked if you are deleting the session just like i said previously?

Comment: I don't know how to check it ...bcoz...i have so many files and folder in my theme

Comment: It's probably easier to check if your session is destroyed everytime:
    var_dump($_SESSION); anywhere where you can see your debug outputs.
Just use anywhere where you can debug - check if the Session id alters. If you are getting the same session_id all the time. If you do, the session is not destroyed - if not, the session is destroyed all the time and you should search for "session_destroy"

Comment: Ok i will check it...